# R: ggplot2 - plots doesn't look right - vertical instead of diagonal lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I'd like to create a plot for 2 categorical variables. Therefore I created two dummy sets but - although they contain the same items - they look totally different. Same happens with my real data as well.

I also tried to perform it with ordered columns, same result.

Please see attached my coding, the three plots (plot 2 is the best practice) + real data plot (but anonymized) to show you problem. Don't understand why there are those vertical lines.

Thank you in advance

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat1 <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c("Male","Female","Male","Female")), levels=c("Female","Male"),
  time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
  total_bill = c(17.42, 16.81, 16.24, 13.53)
)
dat1

#plot1: shows horizontal lines although it should look like the plot 2
ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=sex, y=total_bill, group=time, colour=time)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Plot 1")

#different approach for plot1
arrange(dat1 , sex, time)
dat1
#has ordered columns like I wanted it to be

#still looks like plot1
ggplot(data=dat1, aes(x=sex, y=total_bill, group=time, colour=time)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Plot 1 ordered")

dat2 <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
  time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
  total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)
dat2

#plot2: look like I'd like to have it this way 
ggplot(data=dat2, aes(x=sex, y=total_bill, group=time, colour=time)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
ggtitle("Plot 2")
```

Also an outline of the data plot which has those vertical lines in it

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

mydata2

# ####Output (fictive data but same problem as with my real data, still vertical lines in it but should only have 2 lines like in plot2) 
# group NM  score
# 1     KG               S 2537.94514
# 2     EG               S 1766.39019
# 3     KG               S 3970.91802
# 4     KG               S 4089.14939
# 5     KG               S 2795.42964
# 6     EG               S 2286.60411
# 7     KG               S 4027.22993
# 8     KG               S 1030.18328
# 9     EG               S  719.73679
# 10    EG               S  724.93663
# 11    EG               S 2929.03717
# 12    EG               S  521.55736
# 13    KG               S 1435.85625
# 14    EG               S 1496.39471
# 15    EG               S 3521.25827
# 16    KG               S 2138.17928
# 17    EG               S 1233.86267
# 18    KG               S  591.33086
# 19    EG               S 2171.97341
# 20    EG               S 3871.92536
# 21    EG               S  468.10133
# 22    KG               S 2419.67419
# 23    KG               S 1338.29305
# 24    KG               S 1629.33862
# 25    EG               S  560.39680
# 26    EG               S  546.22468
# 27    KG               S 3398.94647
# 28    KG               S 1117.72716
# 29    EG               S 2794.90527
# 30    EG               S 3606.77693
# 31    KG               S 3558.67156
# 32    KG               S  196.64992
# 33    EG               S 2174.69930
# 34    EG               S 3444.10732
# 35    KG               S  670.60907
# 36    EG               S 3719.20997
# 37    KG               S   65.76227
# 38    EG               S 3420.12225
# 39    KG               S 1405.83738
# 40    KG               S 2859.33873
# 41    EG               T 1296.75111
# 42    EG               T  436.53580
# 43    KG               T  213.09334
# 44    EG               T 2073.70465
# 45    KG               T 1679.98816
# 46    EG               T 1599.26738
# 47    EG               T  777.65179
# 48    EG               T 1738.45395
# 49    KG               T 3269.54120
# 50    EG               T 3506.07302
# 51    EG               T 1764.61915
# 52    EG               T  493.47846
# 53    KG               T 1729.02949
# 54    EG               T 1454.57702
# 55    EG               T 2577.32018
# 56    EG               T  295.08653
# 57    EG               T 3811.24064
# 58    KG               T 2320.35879
# 59    EG               T 1285.65291
# 60    KG               T 3600.26095
# 61    EG               T 3738.89452
# 62    KG               T 3472.53512
# 63    KG               T 1203.33462
# 64    EG               T 1809.41229
# 65    EG               T 3536.17972
# 66    EG               T 2637.59869
# 67    KG               T 1279.44567
# 68    KG               T 1141.81247
# 69    KG               T 3951.54206
# 70    KG               T 1940.11505
# 71    KG               T  192.74602
# 72    KG               T 1235.81839
# 73    EG               T 1907.09384
# 74    KG               T 1772.86806
# 75    KG               T  997.92437
# 76    KG               T  217.81433
# 77    KG               T 3595.69359
# 78    EG               T  910.07955
# ####End of output

ggplot(data=mydata2, aes(x=group, y=score, group=NM, shape=NM, colour=NM)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=NM), size=1) +     # Set linetype by sex
  geom_point(size=3, fill="white") +         # Use larger points, fill with white
  expand_limits(y=0) +                       # Set y range to include 0
  scale_colour_hue(name="Sex of participant",      # Set legend title
                   l=30)  +                  # Use darker colors (lightness=30)
  scale_shape_manual(name="Sex of participant",
                     values=c(22,21)) +      # Use points with a fill color
  scale_linetype_discrete(name="Sex of participant") +
  xlab("Group") + ylab("Score") + # Set axis labels
  ggtitle("Data") +     # Set title
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position=c(.7, .4))           # Position legend inside
# This must go after theme_bw
```

[Plot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSUeq.png)

[Plot1 ordered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYUig.png)

[Plot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZOel.png)

[Data plot which looks wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RhGD.png)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow.  You are likely to get some down voted because of how you asked the quest for example it is preferred to put the code in the question not link it.  Don't worry if you edit people will up vote you.

Comment: Thank you :) I have changed it after your hint.
Should I change something else to avoid down votes?

Comment: You actually have a missplaced ) for the sex variable in dat1(and you don't need the levels argument anyway).    This is pretty close to a minimal example which is good.  I'm not sure what it is exactly that you want to get, however. What is the line geom supposed to be showing?

Comment: dat1,dat2 are coming from a tutorial to understand how I can create my real plot (see Data plot which looks wrong).
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/

I just wanted to understand why there are vertical lines in it. Now I understand that it was due to the fact that I had a 1:1 binding regarding sex:time. Don't know what the line geom should show. Just wanted to create the graph. As said those are dummy data. My real problem is the Data plot but has similar problems (but no binding problem) as the dummy plots.

Comment: But do you see the error with the parenthesis? It should be `dat1 <- data.frame(
    sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
    time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
    total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)
`

Comment: To make a Minimal Reproducible Example you need to eliminate all the extra pieces that make it more complex than it needs to be, for example the theme, the title, etc.  Also why have color, shape and linetype all represent the same variable? Simplify so that people can help you. Perhaps try using one of the sample data sets as your example.

Comment: The data you provided is not at all like the data in the example since in the example code the means of the 4 combinations have already been calculated before plotting.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do but you probably want to calculate the mean scores for the 4 groups. In this case you'd be better off doing something like a grouped box plot with a segment joining the points within the pairs.

Answer (score 2):

the data2 that makes the plot you want looks like this:

```
> dat2
     sex   time total_bill
1 Female  Lunch      13.53 # female has lunch and dinner
2 Female Dinner      16.81
3   Male  Lunch      16.24 # male has lunch and dinner
4   Male Dinner      17.42
```

However your `data1` before and after the arrange looks like this:

before

```
    sex levels   time total_bill
1   Male Female  Lunch      17.42
2 Female   Male Dinner      16.81 # female only has dinner
3   Male Female  Lunch      16.24 # male only has lunch
4 Female   Male Dinner      13.53
```

after

```
     sex levels   time total_bill
1 Female   Male Dinner      16.81 # female only has dinner
2 Female   Male Dinner      13.53
3   Male Female  Lunch      17.42 # male only has lunch
4   Male Female  Lunch      16.24
```

In both data sets females either only have lunch and males only have dinner. Also for the levels column there is the same problem.

So the lines in your plots are drawn between the two female points at dinner, rather than across females points at lunch and dinner.

---

For your updated question, I run your code with the column names like this:

```
#  group NM sex    score
#     1 KG   S 2537.945
#     2 EG   S 1766.390
#     3 KG   S 3970.918
```

and get this? what is the issue?

[image]

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you a lot :) I have added as well a short outline of the data plot (Data plot which looks wrong). It still doesn't make sense to me that I have those vertical lines in it. Those are not error bars.

Comment: you need to provide minimum data for the pot you are still having trouble with or its not possible to help identify where you are going wrong.

Comment: I have added a data set (78 entries) with fictive data, plot looks the same like the one with real data. Still vertical lines in it. I would like to have just two lines like in the plot2 example.

Comment: what re those column names? the dont match the plot code

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Now they do.